# unity3d - large file with animations

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a project where a large truck model is used (around 500MB), very detailed cad model is converted to fbx format in 3dsmax.
There are animations in the fbx model too.

Question 1:
Should I have all the animations as clips in the same fbx file or have separate animation files.
As having seperate fbx files for each animation will increase the overall app size.

Question 2:
How to optimize the mesh which is around 500MB with lots/plenty of child objects (as is it is a very detailed mesh) for performance. Will culling reduce draw-calls or combining mesh reduce draw-call. Is there a way to reduce tris/polycount in the mesh for optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you really care about the app size - go for the same file. Otherwise it's generally much more convenient to have separate .fbx files for animations.
2. You can try limited dissolving and decimation in Blender to reduce the vertices/poly count.

Comment: In case of using separate fbx files should all the fbx files be loaded before the start of the scene.

Comment: If you're using Mecanim to control your animations then they should load automatically - I am not sure though.